# Data retention on storage devices?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, charts, storage

Is there any official table out there that shows how many years can a storage device retain data before it becomes unreadable?

Storage devices: USB memory sticks, classic hard drives, SSDs, optical disks, perhaps others?

Comment: Good question! Can you describe a bit more where you've already looked, and what sort of information you've turned up that wasn't what you're looking for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The article [Data storage lifespans: How long will media really last?](https://www.arcserve.com/blog/data-storage-lifespans-how-long-will-media-really-last)
contains a lot of information. 
[An earlier version of it](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503061606/https://www.storagecraft.com/blog/data-storage-lifespan) concluded with this summary:

> - Magnetic data and cassette tapes: 10-20 years
> - Nintendo Cartridge: up to 10 years
> - Floppy Disk: 10-20 years
> - CDs and DVDs: 5-10 unrecorded 2-5 recorded
> - Blu-Ray: Not certain, probably over 2-5 recorded
> - M-Disc: 1,000 years (theoretically)
> - Hard Disk: 3-5 years
> - Flash Storage: Depends on write cycles, 5-10 years or more <sup>1</sup>

________________ 
<sup>1</sup> **I THINK THIS IS INCORRECT
in the case of a powered-down SSD.** 
The over-hyped article [Enterprise SSDs, Powered Off,
Potentially Lose Data In a Week](https://hardware.slashdot.org/story/15/05/10/0936213/enterprise-ssds-powered-off-potentially-lose-data-in-a-week), at Slashdot, as the title says,
suggests that they last as little as a week –
but the reality is some months or a low number of years if powered down.

I've done some reading in the past on this kind of thing, and have formed the following conclusion based on consensus from articles, studies and technical discussions. 
My research (over time) suggests -

I can't speak for memory sticks, but I have done some significant research into some of the other areas and can advise -

Hard drives - no specific storage span, problems are likely to be with failure rate.   Nominally expect a 5 year lifespan of a hard drive, although RAID and backups are important as failure is reasonably likely before the 5 year period.

SSD's are 10 times more reliable then hard drives.  As long as they have power to them and have not been written to so much that the cells wear out,
they should last many years (not sure they have been around enough for "in real life" figures to emerge).   Powered off consumer grade drives actually fare better then enterprise drives.  Theoretically, an enterprise drive might last only 3 months in bad storage conditions, although a year is typical. 
Consumer grade drives are apparently a few times that. 
Storage time decreases as temperature increases.

Optical disks will vary depending on the quality of the media, and if they are pressed (i.e., last longer) or burned – although one of the early burnable CD disks, and landed up reading from without any issues whatsoever after 12 years – this would not be expected though.

[Tapes are often quoted in the magnitude of 30 years](http://searchdatabackup.techtarget.com/tip/How-long-does-tape-last-really) if stored properly.

Comment: Great article you found.  If the information is accurate, there are going to be A LOT of unhappy people in the future who have images or other data stored on CDs, hard drives, or flash storage.  According to the table, it looks like the best choices are to go back to floppy disks and cassette tapes (or M-Disc media/engraver)!

Comment: Floppy disk waaat?? I worked with a lot of them when I was in school and every single one of them had issues with bad sectors. I dont believe that

Comment: Agree the HD floppies used on PC did not make it much past 10 years, depending on the original quality of the media,  most wouldnt make it 20. Hard drives one would have to define if they are spun-up (3-6years) or stored properly 10-20years plus.

Comment: I can’t believe that I need to tell you this, but please don’t use code formatting for plain text. And especially don’t post 278-character long lines in code blocks.

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні Maybe consider its a 8+ year old post, but thank you for improving the formatting.